# Twitter bootstrap href in modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

```
 <div id="deleteModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-body">
        <span><i class=" icon-info-sign"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <a class="trashconfirm btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" href="javascript:void(0)">Yes</a>
       <a class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">No</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am using jquery to set the hre.

```
     $(".accordion").on('click','.dairytrash',function() {
   var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
   var ele = $(".modal-footer .trashconfirm ");
   ele.attr('href','<c:url value="/delete?id='+id+'" />');
     });
```

The href is also setting properly but when i click nothing is happening.

Comment: `<c:url...` isn't a valid URL. It looks as if you're trying to use server side constructs on the client side.

Comment: No i am finally seeing the correct url to set using firebug like /Spring-Security/delete?id='123456'

Comment: You are trying to use a JSP url in Javascript, i dont think that url gets parsed by JSP and translated into a valid URL for the client side. Im not sure this is the problem though.

Comment: <a class="trashconfirm btn btn-info" href="/Spring-Security/deletediary?id=1363599032377" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</a> .That what firebug is showing me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `data-dismiss="modal"` on a button (which you do), Bootstrap will attach a click-handler on it to hide the modal if the button is clicked. That handler calls `preventDefault()` on the event, so any default actions (like following a `href`) won't be triggered anymore.

If you want to both call a URL when the button is clicked *and* hide the modal, you're going to have to use Javascript to attach an event handler to your button which will both call the URL and hide the modal.

Comment: Does this explain why hrefs within a modal won't fetch the new URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the event hooks described in the Bootstrap Docs (http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html), like so :

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden', function () {
  // do something…
})
```